# Concatenate output from template file inside twig for loop to variable?

Tags: php, twig

I have a situation where I need to `include` a template file inside another template and output it in a `for` loop. The problem I am having though, is that it's outputting to a container and I only need the container to render once, but I need the included template to render on all iterations of the loop.

```
{% for details in array %}

  {% set data_details %}
    {{ include('data.html.twig') }}
  {% endset %}

  <!-- Other HTML needed in the loop -->

  {% if loop.first %}
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>
        {{ data_details | raw }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, the `{% if loop.first %}` prevents the container from repeating. But I need `data.html.twig` to loop on every iteration and append the HTML to the `data_details` variable but the variable only contains the last iteration. I am not that knowledgeable with Twig so maybe I am going about this the wrong way. The documentation says if you wrap something in a `set` it will "capture" the output but that isn't happening for some reason.

Comment: Do you want all the content from loop iterations in `<tr class="table-row"><td> </td></tr>` ? Or show you expected markup

Comment: Yeah. The content from every loop should be contained in `<tr class="table-row"><td> /* final looped content */ </td></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, the iteration does overwrite the already set variable. 
To append to the already set variable , you can repeat/output the variable in the wrap to recapture/concatenate it

```
  {% set data_details %}
    {{ data_details | default('') }}
    {{ include('data.html.twig') }}
  {% endset %}
```

Comment: This worked, however I also had to create the variable before the loop. So I just put `{% set data_details = '' %}` at the top of the template. Thanks.